# Biometric vs Biometrical

Tags: meaning, word-choice, suffixes

Try to google this but doesn't seem it's been created before.

I'm wondering which one I should use between BiometricWorker or BiometricalWorker.

What are the differences between Biometric and Biometrical?

Comment: Google is a useful tool, but did you also try a dictionary?  Which one?  By the way,  "variable naming" is generally considered off topic, since they are not part of natural English.    So what is a "biometric(al) worker"?  A person who measures biometrics?

Comment: @JamesK If this is indeed a variable name, it's entirely possible that "worker" is a reference to a worker thread in a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). So a "biometric worker" could be a worker thread that does calculations on biometric data.

Comment: I can’t think of any context where I’d say “metrical” rather than just “metric”.

Comment: According to the [the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biometric), there is no difference - they mean the same thing, but "biometric" is more common. I'd advise you to choose "biometric" (the more common choice) unless you are within a research group that has decided to use "biometrical" as their standard word.

Comment: Of related interest: *[Difference between similar words like “electric-electrical”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128133)* Also see at EL&U *[Why is it “geometric” but “theoretical”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581)* and *[What is the difference between -ic and -al?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274988/)*, and to a lesser extent *[“Geometric” or “Geometrical”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171509)* and *[Difference between 'acoustic' and 'acoustical'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341912)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of -ic and -al appears to be a classic case of how the English language's habit of adopting features from other languages can cause confusion: for expert speakers almost as much as learners.

The suffix '-ic' according to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ic), means:

> a suffix forming adjectives from other parts of speech, occurring originally in Greek and Latin loanwords (metallic; poetic; archaic; public) and, on this model, used as an adjective-forming suffix with the particular senses “**having some characteristics of**”

The suffix '-al' according to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-al), means:

> a suffix with the general sense “of the kind of, pertaining to, **having the form or character of**” that named by the stem, occurring in loanwords from Latin (autumnal; natural; pastoral), and productive in English on the Latin model, usually with bases of Latin origin (accidental; seasonal; tribal). Originally, -al1 was restricted to stems not containing an -l- (cf. -ar1).

So, in origin they mean the same thing and have been borrowed from classical languages, but they are quite often found used compounded together in adjectives in an ambiguous or confusing way.

1. poetic/poetical
2. historic/historical
3. academic/academical
4. biometric/biometrical

Sometimes there *are* significant differences in meaning (above all historic/historical and arguably academic/academical)*, sometimes the differences are extremely difficult to perceive, and are perhaps today obsolete (poetic/poetical)**, and sometimes the existence of two words is a case of a relative neologism like 'biometric' suggests a lack of a well-defined consensus on the best word to use. For instance, the Cambridge Dictionary doesn't include 'biometrical' at all, but there is a long-established *Biometrical Journal*, so it is possible that scientists have perceived a difference in meaning which has not reached dictionaries.

Finally, there are also instances where the 'ic' suffix solely pertains to a noun, while the '-al' ending pertains to an adjective. In these cases the words are not interchangeable and are well-understood to have very different senses.

1. Magic (noun) / Magical (adj)
2. Music (noun) / Musical (adj)
3. Critic (noun) / Critical (adj)

[Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=biometric%2Cbiometrical&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#) shows that for most of the last 120 years 'biometric' and 'biometrical' have co-existed in English, with 'biometric' usually a short distance ahead in popularity until the 1980s, when it began to pull far ahead: presumably at the time 'biometrics' became a more widely known and discussed subject. In British English, however, 'biometrical' ran 'biometric' a much closer race until the 1970s, even pulling ahead of 'biometric' in popularity briefly in the 1970s, at which point 'biometric' suddenly won the fight for dominance, and 'biometrical' fell into obscurity.

*, ** I'm not citing the differences here as they can be found in any dictionary, but the fact I had to look them up myself (with the exception of historical) suggests the differences are not well known.